# Unable to check htaccess file

Tags: apache, drupal, file-permissions

I am new to php and drupal. After i completed work on site in locally i run it  but shows below error in log/error.log

**Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:37590] AH00529: /home/user/public_html/domainname.com/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/user/public_html/domainname.com/public/' is executable**

I gave 777 permission to public folder below like this
**chmod -R 777 public/**

after i googled i changed the permission to .htaccess file
**chmod 644 .htaccess** then
I gave permission to parentdirectory (public) folder
**chmod 755 public/**

then again i installed new one locally(new site) but it shows the same error

but still it shows same error.
Can any one help me from this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `httpd.conf` (or `apache2.conf`) file and search for the `User` and `Group` directives. The values here refer to the user/group which will be used for Apache server.

Next, go to `/home/user/public_html` (or `/home/user/public_html/domainname.com` whichever is the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`) and do this:

```
sudo chown -R USER:GROUP ./
```

where `USER` and `GROUP` are the values of `User` and `Group` directives from above. Once that is done, set the `htaccess` file permissions to `0644` and try.